# Cypher: how to do a COUNT and a MAX/MIN in the same query (same aggregation)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My model is like this:
    (wine_critic)-[REVIEW]->(wine_bottle)

A wine_critic can do many reviews of the same wine_bottle, 
(they don't know it, it is blind tasting)
with each review having a timestamp and a score

So, I want to get the total number of reviews a wine_bottle has been reviewed by a certain wine_critic, across with the MAX/MIN score that same critic has given to that same bottle.

```
START critic=node:critics('ID:5')
MATCH (critic)-[rev:REVIEW]->(bottle)
WITH critic, bottle, COUNT(rev) as total_reviews
RETURN critic.name, bottle.name, total_reviews
```

but also, in the same query I want MAX(rev.score) and MIN(rev.score).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the WITH in this case:

```
START critic=node:critics('ID:5')
MATCH (critic)-[rev:REVIEW]->(bottle)
RETURN critic.name, bottle.name, COUNT(rev) as total_reviews, MAX(rev.score) as max, MIN(rev.score) as min
```

May as well also throw `AVG(rev.score)` and `STDEV(rev.score)` in too.

*Update*:
Ugly workaround in 1.8.x:

```
START critic=node:critics('ID:5')
MATCH (critic)-[rev:REVIEW]->(bottle)
WITH critic, bottle, MIN(rev.score) as min
MATCH (critic)-[rev:REVIEW]->(bottle)
RETURN critic.name, bottle.name, COUNT(rev) as total_reviews, MAX(rev.score) as max, min
```

Comment: That works for COUNT and MAX but when I throw in MIN(rev.score), I get this:
    __SyntaxException: Unknown identifier `rev`.__
Using Cypher on Neo 1.8.2

Comment: In fact I can confirm that when using more than 2 aggregates of the following: COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX I get the same Exception

Comment: Ah, in 1.9 it should work. :( except for STDEV, which was added in 2.0

Comment: I think the workaround I posted will work--wasn't able to test it exactly. It is also not as efficient because it has to do the match twice and also cycle through and match up the bottles for the second query: O(N^2) at least, where N is bottles. If you are definitely only doing one critic lookup at a time you could simplify it a bit.

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit. I realized you don't actually need to START again. Should be more efficient this way, also.

Comment: I can confirm that the workaround works for 1.8.2.
Performance-wise, as you suspect, I am doing this for all wines... so it looks like quadratic, unless pre-computed paths are somehow cached? I am filtering on those that are above a certain number of reviews, so it is acceptable at the moment. Many thanks!